# How to: overflow text above border-top like with border-bottom when height: 0px

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, border

Is there anyway I can `vertical-align` text to appear above the `border-top` like I can below the `border-bottom` when the height is set to `height:0px;`?

HTML:

```
<ul id="experiment" style="background: #FFDD00;">
    <li id="test1"><span class="v-align-bot">Chocolate</span></li>
    <li id="test2"><span class="v-align-top">Potato</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#test1 {
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #648291; /*grey*/
}
#test2 {
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 50px solid #FA8723; /*orange*/
}

.v-align-bot {
    vertical-align: -50px;
}

.v-align-top {
    vertical-align: 50px;    
}
```

The **Chocolate** easily aligns below the `border-bottom`. The **Potato** does align above the `li` *but* the `border-top` follows(?) it as well.

---

**TL;DR:** Is there anyway I can make the `BUTTON`s in this fiddle below align properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/jLYhg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird wishes eh ;) for doing this, actually the border of an element renders outside the element, so there's no straight way of doing this, but still if you want to get the text vertically middle on the borders, than you need to change couple of things in your markup as well as your CSS.

First of all wrap the words using a simple `span` tag, than use the below rules in your CSS

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLYhg/1/)

```
.v-align-bot span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}

.v-align-top span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
}
```

Also make sure you use `position: relative;` on the below id's else they will flow out in the wild.

```
#test1 {
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #648291; /*grey*/
    position: relative;
}
#test2 {
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 50px solid #FA8723; /*orange*/
    position: relative;
}
```